# How to find an element in a boost::fusion::vector at runtime?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++03, boost-fusion

I have here a proprietary implementation of a generic state machine that uses a `std::tr1::tuple` as a transition table:

```
template<State StartState, Event TriggerEvent, State TargetState>
struct transition {...};

typedef std::tr1::tuple< transition< ready      , run      , running     >
                       , transition< running    , terminate, terminating >
                       , transition< terminating, finish   , terminated  >
                       > transition_table;
```

There's a function

```
template<typename Transitions>
State find_next_state( State current
                     , Event event
                     , const Transitions& transition_table );
```

to find the next state in the transition table given a current state and an event.

This all works fine except for this platform's `tuple` implementation not supporting more than 10 items. The same seems to be true for `boost::tuple`, so I am trying to employ `boost::fusion::vector` instead. But it seems [fusion's `find_if`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/query/functions/find_if.html) only takes "a unary [MPL Lambda Expression](http://www.boost.org/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/lambda-expression.html)" — which, I suppose, only works at compile time.

So given the above, how can I implement `find_next_state()`?

***Note:***

This a proprietary embedded platform that supplies only GCC 4.1.2, so we're stuck with C++03+TR1.

Comment: As an alternative workarond, maybe you could pack tuples into tuples?

Comment: How about write your own `find_if`, that will work with fusion-sequence and function at runtime?

Comment: Why do you use `tuple` in the first place? Does `transition` have any state? If it doesn't you can use the `mpl::vector` and `mpl::for_each` to iterate over it in run-time.

Comment: @Angew: Look at the typedef for `transition_table`. What hoops would I require users to jump through if I did that?

Comment: @Abyx: From what I understood, Boost.Fusion is what you use when you have "runtime issues", and `find_next_state()` is called with values only known at runtime. When I looked into it this morning, I guessed I might therefore be better off using Fusion. Of course, I could be wrong, but that's exactly why I came here asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Writing your own `find_if` is rather trivial, except for the "return the found value" part. Since a `boost::fusion::vector` is a heterogenous container, there is no single right type to return. One possible solution that comes to mind is accepting a continuation function that is invoked with the found value:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/size.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/at_c.hpp>

// private implementation details
namespace detail{
// shorthand ...
template<class S>
struct fusion_size{
  static const unsigned value =
    boost::fusion::result_of::size<S>::type::value;
};

// classic compile-time counter
template<unsigned> struct uint_{};

template<class Seq, class Pred, class F>
void find_if(Seq&, Pred const&, F, uint_<fusion_size<Seq>::value>, int)
{ /* reached the end, do nothing */ }

template<class Seq, class Pred, class F, unsigned I>
void find_if(Seq& s, Pred const& pred, F f, uint_<I>, long){
    if(pred(boost::fusion::at_c<I>(s)))
    {
        f(boost::fusion::at_c<I>(s));
        return; // bail as soon as we find it
    }
    find_if(s, pred, f, uint_<I+1>(), 0);
}
} // detail::

template<class Seq, class Pred, class F>
void find_if(Seq& s, Pred const& pred, F f){
    detail::find_if(s, pred, f, detail::uint_<0>(), 0);
}
```

[Live example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47297be5047a20e5)

The `int` and `long` parameters, as well as the `0` argument are just for disambiguation when `I+1` == `fusion_size<Seq>::value`, as both functions would be equally viable. `0` being of type `int` makes the first overload (the final one) preferred.

Comment: That seems to be close enough to what I am looking for that I can adapt it. Re the return value you might want to look at my actual problem. `:)` I always need to return a `State` enum variable, so this is a piece of cake. (In case I don't find a matching there's variants where I need to throw and those where I need to return a pre-defined value, but those I can deal with using a boolean parameter and even more overloading.) That overloading thing seems a bit overly clever and I am not sure I want to put it into this code base, but I'll see if I need it after I massaged this to do my bidding.